# How to access HttpContext.Current.User.Username in WCF service

Tags: wcf

How can I access `HttpContext.Current.User.Username` from a web application in a WCF service?

Comment: You can't - WCF is **not** necessarily using HTTP, and might not be hosted in IIS, either... so there just **might not be** any HTTP Context at all.... What you can do is use the `OperationContext` in your WCF service method

Comment: Can you brief me on how to implement OperationContext in my wcf service method to get the users identity.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Generally you don't - HttpContext is an ASP.NET concept and doesn't apply to WCF unless you run it with ASP.NET Compatibility turned on.

If you want the current user in WCF then use `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity` or get the security context via the [OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx).

Comment: Finally, someone on stacky who doesn't just answer the question asked, but gives what the asker wanted.

Comment: This answer is old and isn't accurate with the latest frameworks. As of .NET Framework 4.6.2, you can use: `OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, with Asp.Net Compatibility mode on, you can access HttpContext.Current.User from a WCF service hosted in the site. See Microsoft's site for details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682(v=vs.110).aspx

If your service is hosted in an Asp.net site you just need to update your web.config to set aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" on the serviceHostingEnvironment element:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```