# Host custom WCF service with authentication within Umbraco

Tags: wcf, authentication, umbraco, membership-provider

I've created a custom WCF service within Umbraco. The service resides in the `Service` folder and seems to be working fine (I can call it and it responds appropriately). Now I want the users to authenticate themselves when they call the service.

To do this I've added these lines into the `web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
 <bindings>
  <webHttpBinding>
    <binding name="RaceManBinding">
      <security mode="None" />
    </binding>
  </webHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="RaceManagerAdmin.RaceManDataService" behaviorConfiguration="RaceManBehavior">

    <endpoint address=""
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              contract="System.Data.Services.IRequestHandler" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="RaceManBehavior">
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"
                                membershipProviderName="UmbracoMembershipProvider" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

When my service is called it should use the Umbraco membership provider to authenticate the users.

My client specificies this by creating a network credential object, like this:

```
var a = new RaceEntities(new Uri("http://localhost:40406/umbraco/Webservices/RaceManDataService.svc")) { Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "secret") };
```

When I inspect the `HTTPContext.Current` I don't see any authenticated users.

What am I doing wrong?

Frederik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to enable ASP.Net Compatibility in order to access the identity via the HttpContext:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"/>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The answer to this question mentions an alternate method: [How to access HttpContext.Current.User.Username in WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6747263/how-to-access-httpcontext-current-user-username-in-wcf-service)

Comment: Hi
I am sorry, but it seems that i've missed some parts of my service.mode-tag. I've included it all now.