# Host custom (wcf)application within Umbraco

Tags: .net, umbraco

I'm trying to host a custom wcf service, or other application within Umbraco.
But the problem I'm getting is, I think due to inheritance problems, that .Net is missing DLLs. The very first error is:
'Could not load file or assembly 'UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter'.

I want to create a subdirectory within the umbraco install, put my custom application there (whether it is ASP.Net WebForms, or WCF, have not decided yet) and create an application in IIS.

I've seen the following question, but that assumes the application actually works already:
[Host custom WCF service with authentication within Umbraco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795958/host-custom-wcf-service-with-authentication-within-umbraco)

Does anyone have the same issue, and am I missing some trivial settings here?

Umbraco version is 6, .Net applications will be .Net 4 or 4.5 on IIS7/IIS7.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an application within a website in IIS, the sub-application inherits the  existing configuration (see [ASP.NET Configuration File Hierarchy and Inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178685%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for details). Any modules or handlers loaded in the root will be inherited and attempt to run in your newly created application, and this is why you are seeing the `UrlRewritingNet.UrlRewriter` error.

Not only that, but apparently the [Global.asax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2027ewzw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) runs for any application requests, even requests to sub-applications. So any sub-applications within Umbraco are going to have issues, because certain assemblies are expected to be loaded.

It's probably best to just merge the configuration settings and run the WCF service from within the root application. You can still put the `.svc` file in a sub directory, but it won't work as a sub application.