# Read System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.UserName

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the userName of the connected user in my application but the `System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials.UserName` is always empty.

Someone can suggest me how i can do to get it with this method ?

```
var ClientCredential =  System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
Console.writeLine("UserName : " +  ClientCredential.UserName);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "connected user"? Do you mean the Windows user running the application?

Comment: I mean the user connected on my application

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1240379/242520 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.username.aspx and more links are just a quick Google away... http://stackoverflow.com/q/6747263/242520 Look another one...

Comment: "Connected" is a very vague term given the little information you've provided as to what, if anything, the user is connected *to*.

Comment: If you can't explain what does 'connected' mean, then at least tell us what is your application based on? WinForms? WPF? ASP.NET? ASP MVC? WCF? Silverlight? RIA? other?

Answer (score 3):

On the assumption you're using the term "connected" to mean "What is the Windows user name of the person running the application", the answer is to use the `Environment.UserName` property.